# Google Sheets Sending Emails with cc not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to create a script that sends a PDF copy of the sheet with cc to another email, when I send the email it works but the cc email is not getting anything, where could the glitch be at?

```
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {

var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Invoice").getRange("G8");

    var email = emailRange.getValues();

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Invoice"); // Enter the name of the sheet here

    var subject = "Your Little Kid's " + ss.getName();

    var body = "\n Please see attached a copy of your invoice";

    // Base URL
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());

    /* Specify PDF export parameters
    From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
     */

    var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
         + '&size=letter' // paper size legal / letter / A4
         + '&portrait=true' // orientation, false for landscape
         + '&fitw=true&source=labnol' // fit to page width, false for actual size
         + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
         + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
         + '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
         + '&gid='; // the sheet's Id

    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {
            headers : {
                'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token
            }
        }).getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + ".pdf");

    // Uncomment the line below to save the PDF to the root of your drive. 
    //  var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(response).setName(sheet.getName() + ".pdf")

    if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0)
        GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {htmlBody : body,attachments : [response], cc: 'myemail@mailtest.com'});
        }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me at first glance, what happens if you try `MailApp.sendEmail` instead of `GmailApp.sendEmail`?

Comment: Tried it already but still not getting the cc of it

Comment: I tried you code and it's working fine with the cc email getting the email including the pdf, are you sure the cc email is correct? are you using only one cc email?